why does Python from C fail to load module?
PyObject *python_module;
char *module_filename = "/mnt/USB3/C/Python_from_C/python_processes";

Py_Initialize();
python_module = PyImport_ImportModule(module_filename);
if(python_module == NULL)
{
    printf
    (
        "Failed to load module \"%s\"\n", 
        module_filename
    );
    
    getchar();
}

`
The python_processes.py file exists. The returned module is always NULL. The PyImport_ImportModule() function emits no error message,
I have tried many Python initialization schemes (there are rather too many) and all result in the module not being loaded.
Here is another attempt. This really does crash.
Py_Initialize();

python_file_name_pValue = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("python_processes.py");
python_file     = PyImport_Import(python_file_name_pValue);
python_function = PyObject_GetAttrString(python_file, "image_processing");

And here is another attempt:
PyObject *load_python_function3
(
    char *python_file_name, char *python_function_name
)
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *python_function;

    pName = PyUnicode_FromString(python_file_name); 
    
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    if(pModule == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to load python_moduke\n");
        
        getchar();
    }
    
    python_function = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, python_function_name);
    if(python_function == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to load python_function\n");
        
        getchar();
    }
    
    return python_function;
}


It doesn’t seem to crash, it just returns NULL. It does that because PyImport_ImportModule expects a module name, not a filename; and at any rate you don’t seem to have given it a filename either, just a path fragment with an incomplete filename component.

In my example "python_processes" is deliberately  the part name of  the file "python_processes.py". I dropped the extension because Python seems to want that in other contexts. Even with the "py" no module is loaded.  It is likely my ignorance of Python that I assume a file is a module. I know the Python file I want to use and the function within it. All very simple but after a day of thrashing around I have made no progress.

I'm guessing there is a hierarchy of file -- module -- function ?

As and when I get this working I'm going to write a simple function that takes the name of a file and the name of a function and returns a PyObject for the function. I'd like to hide all the fuss of the initialization and the layered conversions.

You cannot import a module by file path, even if you take the .py off. The import system doesn't work like that.

PyImport_Import works exactly as import would in Python. You can't import /mnt/USB3/C/Python_from_C/python_processes in Python, so you can't do that in C.

As you can probably tell I'm not a Python user. There are a couple of Python programs that use neural networks and, for me, the simplest way to use them was to call the Python code from C. I have a large body of C code.

I just want to call a Python function in some Python code and be done. Much of what I need done is in the C code. A nice simple interface to a Python file containing the function is all I need. Somehow I have lost the recipe that once worked for me. The code that forms the tuple to call the Python function etc. is likely fine, I just can't get things to load !

The code immediately above has the C prototype I want. Give it a Python filename and a Python function name, (within the file) and have it return a PyObject pointer to the function. It should be simple but it has me quite stuck.

@user2731097 because that's not what PyImport_Import takes. It takes a module name not a filename.

I read that a Python "module" is a file that contains Python code. The "name" of the "module" is simply the filename without path or extension... Maybe I have to set some path so that the interpreter can find the "module" since the "module" name has no path or extension.

Given that, my file "/mnt/USB3/C/Python_from_C/python_processes.py" has somehow to be translated into just "python_processes" as a module name. And somehow the interpreter has to find it.

@user2731097 At this point you just need to concede that you will need to look at the documentation of the function you’re calling (and follow the links you find there).

Been there done that.

I read: "The default sys.path does NOT include the current directory on any platform. What it usually includes is the script directory." This is, of course, annoying.
